# GMSIndoorDisplay: How to force the change to an specific floor

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using the GMSIndoorDisplay Class of Google Maps. I can setup a view with a default floor. The user can change the floor by pressing any floor in the list of floors. Is there a way to programatically force the change of floor on an existing loaded ViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do it. By saving the current building object we can change the active level of GMSIndoorDisplay and then force a call to the delegate:

```
- (void) didChangeActiveBuilding:       (GMSIndoorBuilding *)   building    [optional]
```

This way, the following delegates will be triggered automatically:
    - (void) didChangeActiveBuilding:       (GMSIndoorBuilding *)   building    [optional]

```
- (void) didChangeActiveLevel:      (GMSIndoorLevel *)  level   [optional]
```

Comment: Can u explain that a little bit clearer? How can u force the delegate to change the room?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it looks like you can't do this. Each building has a default floor which will be selected when the picker is first displayed.

Comment: Verma, I did find a solution to it. Have a look at the anwser. Thanks for the answer though

Answer (score 0):

well, you would need to have all the levels in the building and the current selected floor.

```objc
- (void)mapViewDidFinishTileRendering:(GMSMapView *)mapView {
    if(!selectlevel)
        selectlevel = mapView.indoorDisplay.activeBuilding.defaultLevelIndex;
    allLevels = mapView.indoorDisplay.activeBuilding.levels;
}

- (void)down:(id)down {
    if(selectlevel>0){
        selectlevel = selectlevel -1;
        mapView.indoorDisplay.activeLevel = allLevels[selectlevel];
    }
}

- (void)up:(id)up {
    if(selectlevel< [allLevels count] -1){
        selectlevel = selectlevel +1;
        mapView.indoorDisplay.activeLevel = allLevels[selectlevel];
    }
}
```